Specifying intercept/offset with nls (fitting logistic curve) in R
When estimating a linear model with R, one can force a y-intercept by using the offset argument, e.g.
my_linear_model = lm(y ~ 0 + x, offset=rep(my_intercept, length(x))

I'm trying to fit my data to a logistic sigmoidal curve, using
my_sigmoidal_model = nls(y ~ SSlogis(x,Asym, xmid, scal))

However, if I want y to be some specific value at x = 0, using the same construct as for the linear model, e.g. ~0 + x and specifying the offset) does not work, nor do I see a similar option in the documentation for nls unless I misunderstood something.
What is the most straightforward way to do this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/79096890/1412059
